# Observing changes to Realm result set

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm working on an iOS app that uses a Realm database.  In my `AppDelegate`, I define a Realm result set like this:

```
var results: Results<RealmWidget>!
var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    if results == nil {
        results = realm.objects(RealmWidget.self)
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I observe this result set for changes like this:

```
if notificationToken == nil {
    notificationToken = results.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        switch changes {
        case .update(_, _, let insertions, _):
            if insertions.count > 0 {
                // show badge on tab bar
                // play sound to get the user's attention
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Anytime a new `RealmWidget` object is inserted in the database (which happens as a result of receiving data from a server), I want to show a badge on the `UITabBar` in my UI.  This code appears to be working properly.

In another part of my app, I have a view controller with a `UITableView` that is used to display all of the `RealmWidget` objects (sorted by a timestamp).  Inside of that view controller, I also have a result set that I observe for changes so I know when to reload the tableview.  That code looks like this:

```
var results: Results<RealmWidget>!
var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      results = RealmHelper.getRealmWidgets() // helper method that  queries Realm for all of the Widget objects and sorts them by timestamp
      notificationToken = results.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self!.tableView.reloadData()
          }
      }
  }
}
```

This code also appeared to be working properly until I added code to play a sound into the observation block in my `AppDelegate`.  Then I realized that anytime I *delete* a row from the `UITableView` in this view controller, I was also hearing the sound play.  This was unexpected because I should only be adding the badge to the `UITabBar` and playing the sound when there is an insertion, not a deletion.

I added some debug code into the observation block that's defined in my `AppDelegate` so it looks like this:

```
if notificationToken == nil {
    notificationToken = results.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        switch changes {
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            print("widget deletion count: \(deletions.count)")
            print("widget insertion count: \(insertions.count)")
            print("widget modification count: \(modifications.count)")
            if insertions.count > 0 {
                // show badge on tab bar
                // play sound to get the user's attention
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, switch to the view controller with the tableview and then delete one of the rows (which causes the corresponding `RealmWidget` object to be deleted from the database), I see the following output printed in the debug console:

```
widget deletion count: 2
widget insertion count: 1
widget modification count: 0
```

A couple of things about this are unclear to me:

- why is the deletion count 2 when I only deleted one RealmWidget object?
- why is the insertion count 1 when I didn't add/insert any RealmWidget objects?

If anyone can explain what's happening here I would certainly appreciate the help!

**-- EDIT --**

I added the same debug code into my observation block that is defined inside the view controller and noticed something else strange.  When this "problem" occurs, I see this output in the debug console:

```
widget deletion count (AppDelegate): 2
widget insertion count (AppDelegate): 1
widget modification count (AppDelegate): 0

widget deletion count (View controller): 1
widget insertion count (View controller): 0
widget modification count (View controller): 0
```

So the observation block in my view controller shows 1 deletion but the observation block in my AppDelegate shows 2 deletions and 1 insertion!  Oddly enough, this doesn't happen 100% of the time.  If my `UITableView` is showing 10 `RealmWidget` objects and I delete them one at a time, about 75% of the time, I see the above output in the console.  But the other 25% of the time, the output is exactly what I was expecting to see:

```
widget deletion count (AppDelegate): 1
widget insertion count (AppDelegate): 0
widget modification count (AppDelegate): 0

widget deletion count (View controller): 1
widget insertion count (View controller): 0
widget modification count (View controller): 0
```

1 deletion in both observation blocks.  I'm even more confused now than I was before!  ;-)

**-- EDIT #2 --**

It appears that this behavior is related to the fact that the `Results<RealmWidget>` in my AppDelegate and the `Results<RealmWidget>` in my view controller are not ordering the query results in the same way.

In my `AppDelegate`, `results` is an unsorted collection of all the `RealmWidget` objects in the Realm.  But in my view controller, the helper method that I use to define `results` is a **sorted** collection of all the `RealmWidgets` objects in the Realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question to Realm via GitHub and got the following response:

> Yes, unsorted results are rearranged when objects are deleted. If you
>   don't ask for an explicit sort order, then the objects are simply
>   listed in the order that they happen to be stored on disk, and that is
>   an unstable order that changes when objects are deleted.
>
> We currently report the object at the end moving to the place of a
>   deleted object as that object also being deleted and then inserted in
>   the new location.

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6130